# How to log rails controller filters during rspec controller tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, filter, controller, rspec

Say I have a controller with many before filters. In the controller test the code is never getting to the #create method though in the spec I do post :create. In my case it was that

before_filter :user_signed_in

was not validating but the test log didn't indicate this so I had to figure it out through turning on / off all the filters in turn. Is it possible to get Rails to do some verbose logging as it processes each filter in turn and output that to the test log?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I've solved the same problem. I'm sure the code below can still be improved a lot and possibly put into a module of it's own. Improvements wellcome.

You'll need to put the following code into the top ActionController, which usually is ApplicationController or whatever the controller is you need to track:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def self.before_filter_with_logging(*arguments, &block)
    filters, conditions =
      ActionController::Filters::FilterChain.extract_options(arguments, &block)
    filter_method_names = filters.map { |fm| fm.to_s }.join(', ')
    logger.info "Setting up before_filter to #{filter_method_names}"

    filter_methods_with_logging =
      filters.map { |fm| (fm.to_s + "_with_logging").to_sym }

    filters.each { |fm|
      define_method( (fm.to_s + "_with_logging").to_sym ) { |*args|
        logger.info "Calling before_filter #{fm}"

        if args.empty?
          send fm
        else
          send fm, args
        end
      }
    }
    before_filter_without_logging(filter_methods_with_logging, &block)
  end

  class << self
    alias_method_chain :before_filter, :logging
  end

  before_filter :your_first_before_filter
```

Tomáš Pospíšek

Answer (score 0):

I don't see, why `logger.info ":user_signed_in called"` within that method shouldn't work. You even could do `puts ":user_signed_in called"`, which prints that line directly between the output of rspec. Won't be pretty, but it may be easier than reading the whole test.log file.

Comment: I think you missed the purpose of the question. I want to avoid hunting down the source code of every filter and inserting a Rails.logger command there. I was hoping that there might be some hooks in rails to allow tracing of the callback sequence.