# Is before_filter in application controller executed before any code in controller in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

There is a `before_filter` `check_access_right` in our `application controller`. Our understanding is that the `before_filter check_access_right` in `application controller` should be executed first when an `action` for a `controller` is called. This seems to be the behavior we observed with our rails 3.2.12 app.

We just get a little too curious and hook up debug (`rubymine 4.5`). What we find in debug is that the `before_filter check_access_right` in `application controller` is executed when launching the app. However when an action such as new is called, the debug goes directly to the `action` code in controller without executing the `before_filter check_access_right`. Is the `before_filter` in `application controller` still executed before any code in a `controller` for every `action`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this can give you a little clues about how its done.

[How to log rails controller filters during rspec controller tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951902/how-to-log-rails-controller-filters-during-rspec-controller-tests/5660475#5660475)

It's about tracking and logging which before_filter will called for your debuging